# How can I set the value of a property on a class that I pass into another class?

Tags: c#

I have an application that looks like this:

```
public partial class MainPage : TabbedPage
{
    public bool DarkTheme
    {
        get { return _darkTheme; }
        set { _darkTheme = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
    bool _darkTheme;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        App.settingsTabPage = new SettingsTabPage(this);
```

And on the SettingsTabPage I have this:

```
public partial class SettingsTabPage : ContentPage
{
    public TabbedPage mainPage;

    public SettingsTabPage(TabbedPage mp)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        mainPage = mp;
```

But when I want to make a change to DarkTheme like this then it cannot find the DarkTheme:

```
        mainPage.DarkTheme << can't find DarkTheme
```

Can someone give me some advice on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside `SettingsTabPage` class, you must either cast `mainPage` to `MainPage` class, or declare type of `mainPage` variable  as `MainPage` class.

either

```
(mainPage as MainPage).DarkTheme = ...
```

or

```
public partial class SettingsTabPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage mainPage;

    public SettingsTabPage(MainPage mp)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        mainPage = mp;
```